# Swipe Action Happens Before Seeing Button - Swift Coding

Tags: swift, edit, swipe, viewcontroller, swipe-gesture

I have an edit button, that you swipe right to see, that takes you to another ViewController. But when I swipe right it instantly takes me to the ViewController instead of revealing the edit button (Sometimes I get a glimpse of the edit button before it takes me there). Is there a way to slow this down or remedy this? I'm using Swift.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)

    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseAdd") as UIViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this code:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseAdd") as UIViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

...to just before `success(true)`. It needs to be what you do when the button is tapped, not something you do now.

Comment: It worked! I'm new to coding and I can't believe the fix was something so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Do you see why?

Comment: That I do. Thanks again!